# $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{xy}{x^2 -y}$.

Tags: limits

I would like to show that the following limit does not exist!

$\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{xy}{x^2 -y}$

Comment: check out the graph for some intuition: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=splot+xy%2F(x%5E2-y)+for+x+in+%5B-1,1%5D+and+y+in+%5B-1,1%5D

Comment: "I would like to"....Is this a book problem or did you make this one up? Doesn't matter, but is there a particular reason why you want this limit not to exist?

Comment: is there a particular reason why you use 2 variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take two paths to $(0,0)$:

for $y=x$, $\lim_{x\to0,y\to0} \frac{xy}{x^2-y}=\lim_{x\to0} \frac{x^2}{x^2-x}=0$

for $y=x^2+x^3$, $\lim_{x\to0,y\to0} \frac{xy}{x^2-y}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^3+x^4}{-x^3}=\lim_{x\to 0}-1-x=-1$

limit does not exist

Comment: I think this is correct...+1 What confuses, perhaps, is that after the substitution it is $\;\frac{x^3+x^4}{-x^3}=-x-1\;$ Why SSSR decide to cancel *at first* only one $\;x\;$ I don't know...

Comment: @DonAntonio Found my mistake, thanks

Comment: @DonAntonio I have corrected my answer

Comment: @SSSR It was correct *also* before...but now it is perhaps easier to see.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose

$$r\cos^2t-\sin t=0\iff r(1-\sin^2t)-\sin t=0\iff$$

$$r\sin^2t+\sin t-r=0$$

This is a quadratic in sine, and its discriminant is:

$$\Delta=1+4r^2\implies \sin t_{1,2}=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+4r^2}}{2r}$$

but $\;\frac{-1-\sqrt{1+4r^2}}{2r}<-1\;$ since $\;\sqrt{1+4r^2}>2r\;$ , so it must be

$$\sin t=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4r^2}}{2r}\implies t=\arcsin\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4r^2}}{2r}$$

For these value of the angle $\;t\;$ , the function isn't defined and thus cannot approach anything when $\;r\to 0\;$ , and thus the limit doesn't exist.